# How to set 2nd row in different color by getElementsbyClass

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I've got the following code:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function showColors() {

var cells = getElementsbyClass("design");
for (var i = 0, len = cells.length; i < len; ++i) {
    cells[i].style.backgroundColor = "#ddd";
}

}

if(document.getElementsByClassName) {

getElementsByClass = function(classList, node) {    
    return (node || document).getElementsByClassName(classList);
  };


 </script>
```

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {

showColors();

  }
 </script>
table id="foo">
<tbody>
    <tr class = "design">
        <td>One</td><td>Two</td><td>Three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class = "design">
        <td>One</td><td>Two</td><td>Three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class = "design">
        <td>One</td><td>Two</td><td>Three</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
 </table>
</body>
```

My question: How can i set every 2nd row in different color by getElementsbyClass(). How you can see, the actual code doesn't work :(. Please do not use JQuery or selectivizr. Please stay on the example :). I need a dynamically example. I know that css would work!!! It is also important: It should work for all browsers!!

Many Thanks for answering :)

Comment: You can achieve this with just CSS3.  Check http://davidwalsh.name/css-tables-css3-alternate-row-colors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why dont you fetch the tbody element, loop over the TR elements and add changing classes like this:

```
var i
  , current
  , rows = document.getElementById('table-body').getElementsByTagName('tr');

for(i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  current = current !== 'class1' ? 'class1' : 'class2';
  rows[i].setAttribute('class', current);
}
```

​

you could see a working example at js-fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VF3Ay/3/

Comment: But this approach could be the solution to work it in all browsers!

Comment: it works and should work in IE8: 'var i, current,...' there the variable is initialized. you have to copy the whole code!!!

Comment: which value does the variable current have?

Comment: the first time the loop is reached current is null, but is set inside (current !== 'class1' ...) try to copy my code again, i made a typo in the setAttribute and corrected it. see the updated fiddle. you can change the names for the classes (in my example its class1 & class2) to whatever you like. define in your css the background colors for that classes (see the fiddle!)

Comment: finally ;-) just inspected the dom the first time, saw the attr className and did not think about that much ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS:

```
.design:nth-child(even){ background-color:#ddd }
```

Comment: No CSS. I need a dynamically example with class!!

Comment: @user1860908: I'm pretty sure this will work no matter how many rows you add.

Comment: And I need IE8!!! The Code should work for all browsers. tr:nth-child(2n) {

background-color:#c0c0c0;

}
was my first approach, but this only works for IE9

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing the loop does is change the background colour just add 2 to `i` each time instead of incrementing it with `++`:

```
var cells = document.getElementsByClassName("design");
for (var i = 0, len = cells.length; i < len; i+=2) {
   cells[i].style.backgroundColor = "#ddd";
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ytCZa/

If the loop needs to do other things for every row then just test if `i` is divisible by 2 using the modulo operator before setting the colour:

```
if (i % 2 === 0)
   cells[i].style.backgroundColor = "#ddd";
```

But note that you had a typo: you spelled your `getElementsbyClass` function with a lowercase "b" when invoking it but with an uppercase "b" when defining it, which doesn't work because JS is case sensitive. Also that `if` statement was missing its closing `}`.

In the code and demo above I've not used your `getElementsByClass` function at all: it doesn't do anything that `getElementsByClassName` doesn't do, and it depends on `getElementsByClassName` to work, so you don't need it. If you *really* want it anyway for some reason, here's a demo where I've fixed the code to make it work: http://jsfiddle.net/ytCZa/1/

Comment: For ie9 and Firefox work this fine. But I had to determine that it didn't work with IE8 :( Is there a color-statement for IE8 referring to the actual code?!

Comment: IE8 doesn't have `getElementsByClassName()`. Use `document.querySelectorAll(".design")` instead, or use a [polyfill](https://gist.github.com/2299607) if you want to support even older IE without changing your existing code.

Comment: getElementsByClassName() works on IE8!!! I used it for another usecase! And I wouldn't like to use any scripts!! Javascript should be the only one! The color statement .style.backgroundColor is the cause, why code doesn't work for IE8

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` doesn't work on IE8 according to [QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t11), and if you Google "getElementsByClassName IE8" you get any number of other pages confirming that. `style.backgroundColor` has worked since much older IE than v8. What error do you get in your JS console (opened via F12)? Try `document.querySelectorAll(".design")` instead and see what happens - you don't need any external scripts for that.

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps you!

LE. This is better

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function showColors() {
        var cells = document.getElementsByClassName("design");
        for (var i = 0, len = cells.length; i < len; ++i) {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                cells[i].style.backgroundColor = "#ddd";
            }
            else
            {
                cells[i].style.backgroundColor = "#aaa";
            }
        }
    }
    if(document.getElementsByClassName) {
        getElementsByClass = function(classList, node) {    
            return (node || document).getElementsByClassName(classList);
        };
    };


window.onload = function(){
    showColors();
}
 </script>
<body>
    <table id="foo">
        <tbody>
            <tr class = "design">
                <td>One</td><td>Two</td><td>Three</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class = "design">
                <td>One</td><td>Two</td><td>Three</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class = "design">
                <td>One</td><td>Two</td><td>Three</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this command .style.backgroundColor doesn't work for IE8 :(

Comment: http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20121130-zxnp-44kb .. you can try with document.querySelectorAll(".design") instead..